# Apache record redirects in log file?

Tags: apache-2.2

Is it possible to make an entry in a logfile whenever Apache does a certain redirect? I'd like to be able to keep track of which users used the URL that is being redirected from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

> [RewriteLog Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)
>
> Description:  Sets the name of the file used for logging rewrite engine processing
>
> Syntax:   RewriteLog file-path
>
> Context:  server config, virtual host
>
> Status:   Extension
>
> Module:   mod_rewrite
>
> The RewriteLog directive sets the name of the file to which the server
>   logs any rewriting actions it performs. If the name does not begin
>   with a slash ('/') then it is assumed to be relative to the Server
>   Root. The directive should occur only once per server config.